# Pasar variable al dar click en un item de listView a otro activity

Tags: android-studio, json, activity, android-listview

Buenas.
Tengo esta consulta porque soy demasiado nuevo programando en Android Studio y ya no se para donde ir.
Tengo un listView que cargo con datos de una base que tengo en mi pc y obtengo los datos por un archivo php. Eso anda ok, la lista me la muestra.
Lo que me falta es poder dar click en un iten del listView y que me lleve a otro activity donde pueda capturar el ID del registro al que le este haciendo click.
La lista la agrego asi:

```
public ArrayList<String> obtDatosJSON(String response){
    ArrayList<String> listado = new ArrayList<String>();
    try{
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
        String texto;
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length();i++){

            texto = "\n" +
                    "Barrio: " + jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("barrio") +"\n"+
                    "Dirección: " + jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("direccion") +"  "+
                    "Piso Depto: " + jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("pisoDepto") +" "+
                    "Cliente: " + jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("cliente") +"\n"+
                    "Telefono: " + jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("telefono") + "\n" +
                    "Estado: " + jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("estado") + "\n" +
                    "Cadete Asignado: " + jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("cadete") + "\n";
            listado.add(texto);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return listado;
}
```

Despues hice que al dar click en un item me lleve a otro Activity:

```
public void CargarLista(ArrayList<String> datos){
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,datos);
    listado.setAdapter(adapter);
    listado.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),Detalle.class);
            intent.putExtra("ID","");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Lo que no se es como pasar el ID del registro, ahi vi que va en el intent.putExtra.
Aca es donde no se que hacer: Esta bien crear una variable con los datos del JSON??

```
String Idetalle = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");
```

Pero dsp a esa variable no me deja llamarla o no se como hacerlo dentro del intent.putExtra.

Me guían mas o menos como poder lograr lo que necesito?

**Inclusive me serviria si lo ven y me comentan que esta todo mal desde el comienzo asi buscaria otra forma de hacerlo.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu código va bien encaminado. Una forma de conseguirlo es utilizar el adaptador al cual le pasas los datos. 
Por ejemplo, asumiendo que "datos" contiene los ids que quieres pasar:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),Detalle.class);
            intent.putExtra("ID",datos.get(position);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

En la siguiente actividad sólo necesitarías recoger el extra. Por ejemplo:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String id = bundle.get("ID");
```

Si quieres pasar más datos a la siguiente actividad te recomiendo que te crees un adaptador personalizado, se hace creando una clase que extienda por ejemplo a BaseAdapter.

Comment: Te amo Carmen <3 Muchisimas gracias!!!!

Comment: Un placer  Juan :)

Answer (score 1):

Respondiendo a la siguiente pregunta:

Lo mejor es que te crees e implementes una adaptador propio, que te permite manejar más datos de forma independiente, yo en estos casos generalmente creo a partir del json un array para cada tipo de dato y los paso a un adaptador de este estilo:

```
public class UnidadAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private List<String> id,barrio,direccion,...;

    public UnidadAdapter(Context context1,
                         List<String> id1,
                         List<String> barrio1,
                         List<String> direccion1,
                         ...) {
        context = context1;
        id = id1;
        barrio = barrio1;
        ....

        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return id.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return id.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View mView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listunidad,viewGroup,false);
/*Esto me permite darle formato en un layotu propio*/
        TextView tv_id_unidad = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_id_unidad);
        tv_id_unidad.setText(id.get(i));
        ...
        return mView;
    }
```

Y luego implemento el adaptador en la clase.

```
final UnidadAdapter unidadAdapter = new UnidadAdapter(this,id, ....);
        listView.setAdapter(unidadAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),Reservas.class);
                intent.putExtra("ID",id.get(i));            


                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Es ir un paso más allá, pero verás que es mucho más versatil. Anímate y prueba.

Comment: Muchas gracias Carmen, voy a intentar con eso. Se agradece la predisposición y la buena onda.

Comment: Estupendo, creo que es lo que más se aproxima a lo que buscas. Solo como dato extra por si quieres investigar un poco más adelante, en el extra puedes pasar objetos complejos, pero necesitas crear clases para estos objetos que extiendan a serializable o parcelable para interpretarlos adecuadamente.

Comment: Es exactamente lo que hice jaja muchas gracias por todo, proyecto terminado =)

Comment: Pues entonces enhorabuena

Answer (score 0):

Carmen te pido me saques una ultima duda:
 Con lo que me pasaste paso los datos los capturo y los muestro en otra clase:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String id = (String) extras.get("ID");
textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView .setText(id);
```

Y lo paso con todo esto:

```
public void CargarLista(final ArrayList<String> datos){
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,datos);
listado.setAdapter(adapter);
listado.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
        Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),Detalle.class);
        intent.putExtra("ID", datos.get(position));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
}

public ArrayList<String> obtDatosJSON(String response){
ArrayList<String> listado = new ArrayList<String>();
try{
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
    String texto;
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length();i++){
        texto = "\n" +
                "Id: " + jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id") +"\n"+
                "Barrio: " + jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("barrio") +"\n"+
                "Dirección: " + jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("direccion") +"  "+
                "Piso Depto: " + jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("pisoDepto") +" "+
                "Cliente: " + jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("cliente") +"\n"+
                "Telefono: " + jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("telefono") + "\n" +
                "Estado: " + jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("estado") + "\n" +
                "Cadete Asignado: " + jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("cadete") + "\n";
        listado.add(texto);
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return listado;
}
```

Lo que necesito no es que me muestre todos los datos, solo que me muestre el ID porque mi intencion final es guardar ese ID en un request para pasarlo a mi archivo PHP y meterlo en una consulta (En el where):

```
RequestParams parametros = new RequestParams();
parametros.put("IdPedido", id)
```

¿Como podría hacer para pasar solo el Id y no todos los datos? ¿Es necesario cambiar la estructura de lo que ya hice?